# Does Asana webhooks only take tasks and projects as resources?

Tags: api, webhooks, asana

I want to create a webhook that will take a workspace as a resource instead of a task or project.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Asana's documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/webhooks#create), when creating a webhook, you're required to enter in a resource ID, which can be either a task or a project.